# How to re-prompt a user after invalid input?

Tags: java

I have a program that asks the user for 12 months worth of rainfall data. The data being entered can not be below Zero.

How do I re-ask the user to enter valid data while the program stays on the same month?

Affected sections of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i< month; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the rainfall for month " +
                    (i + 1) + ": ");
            thisYear[i] = myScanner.nextDouble();
        }
```

Comment: I made an answer below, please accept it if you found it useful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a while loop
For example, let's say we only want to except values between 1 and 12 we could do

```
for(int i = 0; i< month; i++){
  System.out.println("Please enter the rainfall for month " +(i + 1) + ": ");
  thisYear[i] = myScanner.nextDouble();
  while((thisYear[i] > 12) || (thisYear[i] < 1)) {//error message
    System.out.println("ERROR Please enter a valid entry");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please enter the rainfall for month " +(i + 1) + ": ");
    thisYear[i] = myScanner.nextDouble();
  }
}
```

This would re prompt the user for an entry  if it was outside of that range, you can also add additional parameters using || as logical or

Answer (score 1):

```java
     for(int i = 0; i< month; i++){
         System.out.println("Please enter the rainfall for month " + (i + 1) + ": ");
          double d = myScanner.nextDouble();
          while (d < 0){
            d = myScanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive value:");
          }         
         thisYear[i] = d;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
double[] year = new double[12];
int month = 0;
while (month < 12) {
   System.out.println("Please enter rainfall");
   double rain = myScanner.nextDouble();
//check if the rainfall entered is >= 0 only then store it in array and increment month;
   if ( rain >= 0.0) {
      year[month] = rain;
      month++;
   }
//if rain is negative then no value is stored and user is asked to enter rain again 
   else {
      System.out.println("enter a positive value");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to adapt user input and avoid additional checks.

`thisYear[i] = Math.abs(myScanner.nextDouble());`